# Tcp connection with libnet C

Tags: c, tcp, tcpdump, libnet

For an assignment i have to create a tcp hijack attack and one of the first steps i have to take is sending a TCP packet to a server to get a response with a sequence number. The server responds to rlogin requests, i tested with nping on tcp to get a response from the server which succeeds but if i try to use my own created tcp packet I dont get any response.

In the image you can see my packet and the one create by nping, i dont get any response from my own packet but i do from the one created by nping. I find this strange because to my knowledge the packets should be the same.

I have no idea how to find the cause of this problem.

[image]

Comment: Are you connecting with a TCP socket, or are you making a TCP packet yourself and sending it with a raw socket?

Comment: I build my own packet with libnet_build_tcp and followed by the appropriate layers and send it using libnet_write

Comment: Did you check all the differences between your packet and the one that works?

Comment: As far as i know the only differences are the seq number, the id and some bytes in the payload

Comment: I would check: layer-2 header. IP checksum. Make sure there aren't any VLAN tags. Which interface the packet is going out from. Try a source port number higher than 1023.

Comment: The checksum which i give in the ip build function is 0 and im struggeling to find out how to calculate it

Comment: Well there seems to be an IP checksum in your packet so I guess it calculated it for you. Still, calculate it by hand and check it

Comment: Maybe try using a source port **above** the IANA reserved port range for system ports (0-1023).  You're currently using port 1023.  Try something in the user port or dynamic port ranges.  Ref: https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml